# Configure Neo4j 1.9.3 in Spring for HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase (embedded)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, high-availability, spring-data-neo4j

As of now, I was using neo4j 1.8.2 EP edition for clustering 3 instances. I used to have below configuration for my spring application:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="storeDir" index="0" value="E:/Neo4J Enterprise Edition/db1/graph.db" />
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <map>
                <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1" />
                <entry key="ha.pull_interval" value="10"></entry>
                <entry key="ha.server" value="192.168.1.10:6001" />
                <entry key="ha.coordinators" value="192.168.1.10:2181,192.168.1.7:2182" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
```

but as per new changes in neo4j 1.9.3 Enterprise Edition, Zookeeper is no longer used and coordinator is also not longer functional. How can I reconfigure this to work with neo4j 1.9.3 enterprise edition ? any link/resources would be appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: Use the configuration: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome I did 2 changes:

1. I replaced `<entry key="ha.coordinators"` with `<entry key="ha.initial_hosts"`.
2. Updated my `pom.xml` for **neo4j-ha**, **neo4j-kernel**, and **neo4j-management** and other neo4j related libs to latest one i.e. 1.9.3 (initially it was 1.8.2)

and thats it. :)
Thanks